# Create hyperlink when new sheet is created

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code found on the internet. It creates sheets using my template based on a list in my summary sheet.

I want it to make a hyperlink to the sheet in my list.

```
Mal=Template
Sammendrag=Summary
```

Here it is:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList() ' Example Add Worksheets with Unique Names

Dim MyRange As Range, i As Long
Dim ShtName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
With Sheets("Sammendrag")
    Set MyRange = .Range("B10:B69" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

Sheets("Mal").Visible = True

With MyRange
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        ShtName = Trim(.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        If Len(ShtName) Then
            If Not WorksheetExists(ShtName) Then
                Sheets("Mal").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.name = ShtName
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

Sheets("Mal").Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can add a hyperlink:

```
.Cells(i, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(i, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(SHtName).Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(SHtName).Name
```

On click you will jump to Cell A1 of the Sheet.

Comment: After you defined the worksheet name. So currently I guess the best place would be after ActiveSheet.name = ShtNamne.

Comment: It worked, thank you! The problem i have now is that when hyperlink is created it changes the text size and color. Is there any formatting of the cells that prevent it from changing the text style?

Comment: I am not aware of something that can prevent the change, however, you could paste the format of the cell below onto the current cell after creating the hyperlink. Then the format would stay the same. Or you could just add a line that changes the font to the style you need.